# AWS cloudformation spot instance parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to add a parameter in my cloud formation stack that will allow the users to choose between on-demand and spot instances for the launch template, which will initiate the EC2 creation. This stack is designed to launch a workstation for a single user.

Currently there only seems to be one value available for the InstanceMarketType Parameter, does anyone know an alternative way of choosing the instance market type?

```
  InstanceMarketTypeParameter:
   Type: String
   Default: spot
   AllowedValues:
    - spot
    - on-demand
   Description: Choose between on-demand and spot instances.
```

The launch template would look something like this

```
Ec2LaunchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateName: LinuxWorkstation
      LaunchTemplateData:
        InstanceMarketOptions:
          MarketType:
            Ref: InstanceMarketTypeParameter
```

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use `InstanceMarketOptions`? What's wrong with it?

Comment: Instance market options only allows the value of 'spot', so you can't tell it to use 'on demand'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `InstanceMarketOptions` optional using [If](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if):

```
Conditions:

  IsOnDemand:
    !Equals [!Ref InstanceMarketTypeParameter, "on-demand"]

Resources:

  Ec2LaunchTemplate:
      Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
      Properties:
        LaunchTemplateName: LinuxWorkstation
        LaunchTemplateData:
          InstanceMarketOptions:
            !If 
                - IsOnDemand
                - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
                - MarketType:
                    Ref: InstanceMarketTypeParameter
```

Comment: I did not think to try use conditions to solve this, that worked exactly as I'd hoped, thanks!!